# How to auto generate a rake migration file with json

Tags: json, migration, rake

Using sqlite3, Rails 4.2.0.
Getting the following error when running `rake db:migrate`.
The problem is that the migration file has the following:

`t.json :blah` and should have `t.column :blah, :json`

My question is, "**How do I get the migration file to auto-generate properly?**"

I used this to generate the migration file:

```
rails generate scaffold rails_app title:string blah:json
```

This puts the `t.json :blah` in the migration file.

```
> ubuntu@host:~/rails_app$ rake db:migrate
> == 20150119183550 CreatePolreqs: migrating ====================================
> -- create_table(:rails_app) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
> 
> undefined method `json' for
> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007f8466ab9680>/home/ubuntu/rails_app/db/migrate/20150119183550_create_rails_app.rb:6:in
> `block in change'
> /home/ubuntu/rails-app/db/migrate/20150119183550_create_rails_app.rb:3:in
> `change' NoMethodError: undefined method `json' for
> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007f8466ab9680> /home/ubuntu/rails_app/db/migrate/20150119183550_create_rails_app.rb:6:in
> `block in change'
> /home/ubuntu/rails_app/db/migrate/20150119183550_create_rails_app.rb:3:in
> `change' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with
> --trace)
```

Comment: I encouter the same issue. seems like migration file always write t.json :blah back to schema file; but schema file need the format of t.column :blah, :json.  maybe it requires rails team to rewrite how schema file is updated. any solution/workaround though?

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite3 adapter doesn't support json columns (yet).

It is supported by postgres: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_postgresql.html.

To switch databases, update your Gemfile and replace

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

with

```
gem 'pg'
```

An alternative to switching databases would be to use a 'text' column instead of 'json', but this would require serializing json yourself and you won't get any of the fancy json query operators provided by postgres.

Looks like sqlite3 recently added support for json columns so this may be supported by the sqlite-ruby adapter at some point in the future:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/10/sqlite-39-released

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby